# Tesing Phoenix Controllers but skip Plugs

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am currently trying to test controllers in a Phoenix project.

I have a rather sophisticated authentication plug (which I test separately). I don't want to provide valid credentials for all controller tests.

Is there a way to skip certain plugs when running a test.

I experimented with `bypass_through(conn, MyAppWeb.Router, [])` but that doesn't seem to hit the controller function at all.

Comment: Do you only want to bypass certain plugs or all of them?

The former case might be very difficult but the latter could be accomplished by calling the controller function directly.

Comment: I only want to exclude certain plugs (authentication in that case)

Comment: In that case the suggestion from cdegroot is the only straightforward one I see

Answer (score 2):

One trick to bypass authentication logic in tests, is to directly assign attributes to the connection.

For example: a lot of authentication libraries expect a `current_user` to be assigned to the connection. This can be *faked* in the specs by just assigning the user, without any real authorization.

So, if your plug checks if a certain `conn.assign` is present, you can easily fake that in your tests.

An example of a controller test with some setup to do a fake login:

```
setup [:create_user, :login_as_registered_user]

def create_user(_) do
  user = MyApp.insert_user(%{name: "...", email: "..."})
  {:ok, user: user}
end

def login_as_registered_user(%{conn: conn, user: user}) do
  conn = Plug.Conn.assign(:current_user, user)
  {:ok, conn: conn}
end

# ...Lots of tests...
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to do it in your application code:

```
if Mix.env != "test" do
  plug MyAuthenticationPlug
end
```

then during testing, your plug will not be compiled in.